# BIOS damage/change or virus: BIOS password not appearing and bitlocker suddenly asking for encryption phrase

Tags: windows, bios, encryption, virus, bitlocker

Approximately 2 years ago I set up my PC (Windows) as follows:

- I set up a BIOS password.
- I encrypted the whole system with a bitlocker
  password, so I need to enter a bitlocker password.

Usually when I turn on my pc I get asked for a BIOS password. This is clearly visible that it comes from the BIOS. The password consists of letters and numbers. Then afterwards usually bitlocker asks for a password, which consisted of 6 numbers.

Yesterday I worked quite long and I also installed Notepad++, which I assume is not "complicated" and does not make any significant changes to the system or bios. This is the only change I made to the system yesterday. Afterwards, I shut down my PC as I usually do, or at least I cannot remember a power interruption or so. Some time in the past I remember that when I shut down (and I really clicked on shut down in the start menu) that when restarting a "resume hibernation" was displayed in the left corner, I cannot remember where exactly, I think directly when I started - but I also had to enter BIOS password and Bitlocker password.

Today I started my PC and I could see the BIOS screen and booting. However, **no prompt from the BIOS system to enter a password**. Then Bitlocker appears, but it **asks me for a recovery phrase**. So not the usual password, but the recovery phrase (indeed I set up Bitlocker with a recovery phrase 2 years ago). I didn't enter it yet, because I have no idea why suddenly this change appears. Especially, I do not understand why Bitlocker appears first and not the BIOS password prompt first. So usually even if there is something strange with the Bitlocker encryption I would expect that I still have to enter the BIOS password.

So I wondered what is behind this. Is it:

1. There was a damage / change in the bios system or something caused Bitlocker to ask for the recovery phrase.

or

1. It is a virus / scam / remote encryption that turned off the BIOS password and encrypted my system with another password/recovery phrase or just scams me to enter my encryption phrase or just "did the damage for fun". I personally cannot image that a virus or some hacker is able to remotely wipe my BIOS password and make changes to the Bitlocker system encryption. Or at least it seams not likely for me to be the cause, as someone able to do this would rather try to scam my system and get my banking credentials or personal data or so. I mean of course it's probably possible for the CIA or so, but the step from internet to BIOS settings is like quite far. So usually internet and then some Windows virus ok, but BIOS changes and Bitlockerencryption changes.

**Question**: **Is it scenario 1, 2 or something else? And why am I not asked for the BIOS password anymore?**

I know that there are several reasons that out of a sudden Bitlocker can switch to ask for the recovery phrase, like changes to BIOS, hardware or so.

I did not perform any BIOS updates on my own or make changes to Bitlocker .

Comment: Most likely a Windows Update or a BIOS firmware update. Either can trigger this, and both can be delivered through Windows update automatically. Entering the recovery code (probably needs to be done twice) should return the pc into previous state with asking for bios password and normal bitlocker pin.

Comment: *installed a software, but rather a small one and normally no "complicated" changes to the system or bios from this software* - so, you installed software that you've installed before - do you mean there was an upgrade to some software? Why do you think this software is important enough to mention vaguely and not say what the software is?

Comment: @JaromandaX It is a new software which I did not try before. I cannot say for sure that it did not change something in the BIOS. But I don't think so. It is a regular smaller application, so I would not expect any advanced changes to the system that could lead in a consequence like this.

Comment: I had several Windows Updates the last time / days, but actually not on the day before, at least I think so (I think sometimes it updates in the background). When I clicked on shut down it was a regular shut down, so not install updates and then shut down or restart. I am not aware of any BIOS firmware updates, at least I did not do anyhting manually here.

Comment: yes, because malware always advertises itself as malware

Comment: @JaromandaX I did not mention it as I did not want to put the attention to it. It was notepad++. It is a quite well known software and I don't think that a standard application like this would change the BIOS.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by the recovery phrase. Do you actually mean your being asked for the BitLocker Recovery Key?

Comment: Yes, so it is not the normal password number, which consists of 6 numbers, but the longer recovery key/phrase. So it is a combination of letters and numbers which I had to write down / print out while setting up the encryption.

Comment: OK, sorry for being a pest

Comment: Did the CMOS battery go dead and CMOS got cleared? You could check the BIOS version to see if it was recently released and you got it with windows update. If those things are ruled out, then perhaps some malware erased your CMOS and your BIOS settings were reset.

Comment: The only reason BitLocker would be requesting the Recovery Key, is if a detected configuration change was detected, similar to one that would happen when the CMOS configuration was lost.

Answer (score 0):

I am following up with an update and post it as an answer, as this clarifies it:

The idea of Alex to check the BIOS version is a good idea to see the release date. I will try to do this.

I ended up with just giving it a try, i.e. entering my recovery key. Of course I was lucky, as I wrote it down when I encrypted it two years ago. BitLocker indeed then did the recovery and it worked. When I then restarted I had to enter my usual PIN and Windows would start. The only thing that still was different was that the BIOS password prompt was not there anymore. So I entered the BIOS system and set it up again. Now the behaviour is the same as it used to be.

As I had to set up the BIOS password again this seems to me that the comment from Alex is quite right. It seems there was an Update and this also erased the password. I am still a bit worried that Windows basically did this on its own without asking me or giving me a warning that this can have such an impact.